# Create ID automatically for all entries into tables with same foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 19 tables that all have a column named `CompanyID` set as a foreign key that references the `company` table Primary key CompanyID which is set to auto_increment.

Is there a way I can INSERT into all the tables without having to specify the CompanyID in every query? So if I insert into the `company` table first it will get assigned a CompanyID automatically and I need to use that to insert into the other 19 tables but how do I get this information?

The only way I can think of is to auto generate an ID with php but I don't like this method because it won't follow the 1,2,3 convention I want to use. Also another method is to INSERT the information into the `company` run a select after its been inserted and match the company name with the CompanyID and set this as a variable in my script but that seems like a lot of extra nonsense. Is there a better way? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `SELECT @myid = LAST_INSERT_ID();`? (But if you tell us _which_ mysql interface you use, we might give you a better option).

Comment: by interface do you mean phpmyadmin or PDO?

Comment: `PDO` is an answer I was looking for :). [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) is a better option then searching or running that query from me manually. Mind you, edcaracas's suggesting of just making it one procedure is not a bad one at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use last_insert_id();

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO company ....

$id = SELECT last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO othertable (company_id) VALUES ($id)
INSERT INTO yetanothertable (company_id) VALUES ($id)
```

Most DB libraries which handle MySQL will have some dedicated function/method to get this ID without having to do a full-blown query, but the basic mechanism will be the same in all libraries - insert your "core" record, retrieve its auto-generated ID with last_insert_id()-type calls, then use that retrieved ID in all child record insertions.

Comment: What if another person adds an entry immediately after I INSERT into company before it obtains the last_insert_id and gets the wrong id is this a possibility?

Comment: last_insert_id() is specific to YOUR connection to the db. it will only report the ID of the LAST insert YOU performed. it'd be useless otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to Stored Routines. This may help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html